# Compare two objects is string and is equal

Tags: c#

`values` is an `object` array. I need to check whether the 3rd and 4th elements are strings. If this is the case, I need to check whether they're equal.

Here is how I did it:

```
if ( values[2] is string && 
     values[3] is string && 
     ((values[2] as string) == (values[3] as string)))
{
    return false;
}
```

Is there a simpler or shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
return values[2] is string && values[2].Equals(values[3]);
```

It's sufficient to know that one of both objects is a string. If it then equals the other object, this guarantees that the other object is also a string.

Also, note the use of `Equals()` instead of `==` to guarantee a comparison of the string contents as opposed to the object references.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `string.Equals(object)` method is the simplest to use here.

```
 result = string.Equals(value[2], value[3]);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkfd9eh8(v=vs.110).aspx)

> returns true if obj is a String and its value is the same as this instance; otherwise, false. If obj is null, the method returns false.

Comment: I don't see a static method accepting objects as parameters. Would this work without casting value[2] and value[3] to string? You may be able to do this in a try block, and handle the invalid cast exception.

Comment: This does not guarantee that both are strings. `object a = null; object b = null; String.Equals(a, b); // returns True`

Comment: [Max Hampton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2113715/max-hampton) You do not need to cast. The equals method (from object) is overridden by the string class. It is an object method. And this will need a catch for `NullReferenceException` as you cannot call `Equals` on a null object, therefore this method is good when you're sure you don't have null objects.  

Alternatively your could user `String.Compare(objA, objB) == 0` to determine if two objects are equal strings as this handles null too, but might be slower.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check if one of them is a string, because you are checking them both for equality.  If they are equal and one is a string, then both are.

```
return (values[2] is string) && (values[2] == values[3]);
```

Comment: This compares object reference equality instead of the string contents.

Comment: That's true, but doesn't interning ensure that _almost_ every string with equal contents will have an equal reference?  It seems to me that you have to go out of your way for this approach not to work.

Comment: Not that I'm advocating lazy programming.  When I came to C# from Java I always used a .equals method, then did some research which found == was acceptable.

Comment: I don't have to go out of my way for it not to work: `object s = "hel"; s +=  "lo"; return s == "hello"; // returns False` Java's string interning is not that different from C#'s, and relying on string interning is folly. It's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement checks if an object is compatible with a given type. For 
example, the following code can determine if an object is an instance 
of the MyObject type, or a type that derives from MyObject:

```
  if (obj is MyObject)
  {}
```

If that is the case, use for more clear code (c# compiler will take care of efficiency)

Use:

```
 Object.Equals(a, b)
```

it checks the equality of the string content, rather than the 
reference (since the string is immutable, there really cannot be two 
string objects which are referring to the same memory, correct if i'm wrong).
It calls "under the hood" to String.Equals because Equals is virtual.

It is a very obscure way to compare strings, i admit, bad more clear and in the same price.

Answer (score 0):

Use .Net `String.Compare` Method from these examples: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),[2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx)

```
 return String.Compare(values[2], values[3], true) == 0;
```

Comment: `String.compare()` does not accept `object` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to previous answers

```
return value[2] != null && value[2] is string && value[2].Equals(value[3]);
```

From eric lipperts post: http://blog.coverity.com/2014/01/13/inconsistent-equality/#.Vfp63d-qqko

> > In scenario three we must first solve an overload resolution problem to determine what Equals means. The receiver is of type int and it has three methods named Equals:

```
Equals(object, object) // static method from object
Equals(object)         // virtual method from object
Equals(int)            // Implements IEquatable<int>.Equals(int)
```

> > The first one we can eliminate because there are not enough arguments. Of the other two, the unique best method is the one that takes an int; it is always better to convert the short argument to int than to object. Therefore we call Equals(int), which then compares the two integers again using value equality, so this is true.

**From MSDN**

> > IEquatable.Equals Method (T)
> >     Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type.